# Why is there a triple dash (---) in some of my (Rails) locale files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, yaml

In some of the locale files of the project I am currently working on I find
a triple dash in the first line.

Like so:

```
---
de:
  activerecord:

    user:
```

In most of the locale files they are not there. All of them work as expected. 
It seems, that the dashes are in the original Rails locales, but as we hardly have any left this is just a guess.

Any ideas where they come from and what the effect is?

Comment: I still don't understand why this is considered duplicate. While the other question is about removing something from YAML files, this question asks about the meaning of a symbol in YAML files in the context of Rails. Especially beginners, who don't know that Rails' locale files are actually YAML files will be happy to find this question by referring to Rails locale files.